# How to Process messages in stream from last output to sink?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark, and I have a use case where I want to emit the aggregate in an append output fashion. I understand that append mode doesn't go well with aggregates, and spark supports that functionality only if we provide windowing operation (along with watermarking).

Now, what I want spark to do is forget the old messages (messages processed in the stream already), and just take the messages which arrived between the last output and current time (meaning current micro batch), and compute the aggregates on top of it and emit the results.

I think its fairly straightforward, but could not find the examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not necessary that we only used window based aggregations with structured streaming ,we can also do aggregations on event_time column with watermarking set on that column. Below are some points from structured streaming programming guide.

> The aggregation must have either the event-time column, or a window on the event-time column.

> withWatermark must be called on the same column as the timestamp column used in the aggregate. For example, df.withWatermark("time", "1 min").groupBy("time2").count() is invalid in Append output mode, as watermark is defined on a different column from the aggregation column.

for further details [Spark Structured Streaming programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#conditions-for-watermarking-to-clean-aggregation-state).

Secondly,

> Now, what I want spark to do is forget the old messages (messages processed in the stream already), and just take the messages which arrived between the last output and current time (meaning current micro batch), and compute the aggregates on top of it and emit the results.

To do aggregations where old data is not required can be done by setting watermark duration to "0 minutes", which means that the streaming engine will not wait for any old records while aggregation.

Eg -> Suppose we have the following df

```
+-------------------+--------------+
|end_time           |transaction_id|
+-------------------+--------------+
|2020-12-14 15:08:52|d6            |
|2020-12-14 15:08:52|02            |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

Before aggregation set watermark as -

```
val waterMarkDf = df.withWatermark("end_time","0 minutes")
```

Followed by aggretaions. One thing to keep in mind is that structured streaming engine does not guarantee that it will drop all old records while aggregation. For further details about this please read the Spark Structured Streaming programming guide section [Semantic Guarantees of Aggregation with Watermarking](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#semantic-guarantees-of-aggregation-with-watermarking)